# Set an occurrence count to the item in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array with address types like this:

```
var addressTypes = [
   { "id": 748, "type_id": 0, name:"Previous"},
   { "id": 749, "type_id": 0, name:"Previous"},
   { "id": 750, "type_id": 1, name:"Vacation"}
];
```

In my view I should show a name of particular address type and number of it occurrences like this:

```
<span ng-bind="address.name + ' Address ' + ($index == 0 ? '' : $index + 1"</span>
```

How can I manually count and assign a number of occurrences of certain address type to use it in view instead of $index.

For example, in my result array I want to get something like this:

```
[ { "id": 748, "type_id": 0, namne: "Previous", count: 1},
  { "id": 748, "type_id": 0, name:  "Previous", count: 2},
  { "id": 750, "type_id": 1, name:  "Vacation", count: 1 }
]
```

Comment: You should not assign values in a template expression. First transform the array with the desired output, then display it according to the design you've chosen.

Comment: @briosheje the OP never said the assigment would be done in a template expression, "assign a number of occurrences of certain address type to use it in view instead of $index" actually indicates the contrary..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following code,

```
addressTypes.forEach(function(itm) {
  this[itm['id']] = (this[itm['id']] || 0) + 1;
  itm.count = this[itm['id']];
}, {});
```

Just use the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and with its context receiver. That would be enough for doing this. Note, when you are using the context receiver, you cannot use the arrow function. Because arrow function would not allow you to set the context manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` to keep track of occurrence of each name and add count accordingly

***Steps:-***

- Initialize counter as `Map`
- Loop over the `addressTypes` check if that name is present in counter or not
- If it is present add `1` to it's previous value else set it to `1`
- Add count property in final object and set value from counter

```js
let counter = new Map()
var addressTypes = [{ "id": 748, "type_id": 0, name:"Previous"}, { "id": 749, "type_id": 0, name:"Previous"}, { "id": 750, "type_id": 1, name:"Vacation"}];

let dataWithCount = addressTypes.map(obj=>{
    counter.set(obj.name,(counter.get(obj.name) || 0)+ 1)
    return {...obj, count: counter.get(obj.name)}
})

console.log(dataWithCount)
```